# org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on entities.Ques#tion.examId references an unknown entity: long

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I'm trying to setup JPA with a hibernate implementation for the first time with this test project. Ran into the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: ExamModulePu] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:924)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:899)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:59)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
at service.tests.ExamServiceTest.main(ExamServiceTest.java:18)
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on entities.Question.examId references an unknown entity: long
at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:109)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processEndOfQueue(Configuration.java:1536)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processFkSecondPassInOrder(Configuration.java:1457)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1365)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1756)
at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
```

These are my entities:

```
@Entity
public class Exam implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private int numQuestions;
    private int minutesAllotted;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "examId", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Question> questionList;
        // Getters and setters here..
}

@Entity
public class Question implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @ManyToOne
    private long examId;
    private int points;
    private int timeLimit;
    private String text;
    private String category;
    @Embedded
    private List<Answer> answerList;
}

@Embeddable 
public class Answer implements Serializable {

    private int optionNumber;
    private String text;
    private boolean correct;
}
```

This is what my persistence.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="ExamModulePu"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>entities.Exam</class>
        <class>entities.Question</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/exammoduledb" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I haven't created any of the tables, but instead am depending on the `hibernate.hb2mddl.auto` to do so. But I believe my error springs up even before that happens as it can't generate the persistence unit. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I'm making sure I import only `javax.persistence.*;`

Answer (score 81, accepted):

If you look closely at your stacktrace, you will see

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on entities.Question.examId references an unknown entity: long
```

So this field

```
@ManyToOne
private long examId;
```

is causing the problem. `@ManyToOne` has a paramater `targetEntity` which says:

> (Optional) The entity class that is the target of the association. 
>   Defaults to the type of the field or property that stores the association.

Since you haven't provided that parameter, it defaults to `long`, which is not a managed `Entity`.

You'll probably want to use

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Exam.class)
private long examId;
```

otherwise it won't know what to map to. Or even better

```
@ManyToOne
private Exam exam;
```

Answer (score 21):

Just add the class **Team** to the "hibernate-cfg.xml" file, because Hibernate doesn't identify without adding into it.

Comment: Or in persistance.xml.

Answer (score 10):

FYI, this sometimes happens if you have a hibernate annotation:

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity
```

and a JPA annotation:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
```

mixed up

Edit:

Explicitly import the javax annotation.

Comment: what is ur suggestion @CoffeJunky ?

Comment: His suggestion is to exclusively import `javax.persistence.Entity` instead of `org.hibernate.annotations.Entity`.

Comment: This is not the in case of my program but still giving error

Comment: Is it the exact same error message? Could you share your source code?

Answer (score 4):

It took me hours to find the actual issue

I had forgotten the @Entity annotation on the Parent class and the error use to show on the child class.

Answer (score -1):

In my case Hibernate was not able to identify the entity because I had not added that entity in sessionfactory using .addAnnotatedClass(XYZ.class) so it was not able to find that particular entity.