# Complex Inner Joins using Springboot JPA

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, join, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to Springboot JPA, I need my code to fetch the below sql command using JPA

```
**Table Details:**
create table questions (
    id varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    description varchar(200) NOT NULL
);

create table questions_workflow (
    business_id varchar(20),
    parent_id varchar(20),
    child_id varchar(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (business_id, parent_id, child_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES questions(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (child_id) REFERENCES questions(id)
);

**Query:**
select a.business_id, a.parent_id, b.description, a.child_id, c.description
from questions_workflow a
inner join questions b on a.parent_id=b.id
inner join questions c on a.child_id=c.id
where a.business_id=?;
```

I only need the JPA Repository code for this, I think this can be achieved using the **@Query** annotation, the only doubt I have is what should be the return type since I'm fetching custom columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me share my approach and solution.

The repository code for the above query is as follows:

1. Let's create two Entities corresponding to our tables.

```java
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "questions")
public class Question {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String description;

    // Getters and setters...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "questions_workflow")
public class QuestionWorkflow {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "business_id")
    private String businessId;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Question.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Question parentQuestion;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Question.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "child_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Question childQuestion;

    // Getters and setters...
}
```

2. Now, create a class to hold the result of our query.

```java
public class CustomResult {
    private String businessId;
    private String parentId;
    private String parentDescription;
    private String childId;
    private String childDescription;

    public CustomResult(String businessId, String parentId, String parentDescription, String childId, String childDescription) {
        this.businessId = businessId;
        this.parentId = parentId;
        this.parentDescription = parentDescription;
        this.childId = childId;
        this.childDescription = childDescription;
    }

    // getters and setters...
}
```

3. Now, let's create our JPA repository:

```java
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface QuestionWorkflowRepository extends JpaRepository<QuestionWorkflow, String> {

    @Query("SELECT new com.yourpackage.CustomResult(a.businessId, a.parentQuestion.id, a.parentQuestion.description, a.childQuestion.id, a.childQuestion.description) " +
           "FROM QuestionWorkflow a " +
           "WHERE a.businessId = ?1")
    List<CustomResult> findByBusinessId(String businessId);
}
```

Here, you need to replace `com.yourpackage` with your actual package name.

**Remember** that in JPQL, the join operations are performed based on the object model, not the database tables. Hence, we don't need to explicitly mention "INNER JOIN" operations in the @Query annotation for ManyToOne relationships. In the above query, "a.parentQuestion.description" will automatically fetch the description from the Question entity that's joined via the parent_id and similar for childQuestion. The returned results will be wrapped in CustomResult objects and returned as a list.

**Remember** to mark your foreign key columns with @ManyToOne and @JoinColumn annotations in your entity classes. The @JoinColumn annotation defines the actual physical mapping on the database table.

Hope this answer would be helpful.

Comment: Hi louis, a small correction to the code above, the @ManyToOne annotation should be @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Question.class), else it will throw [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076546/org-hibernate-annotationexception-onetoone-or-manytoone-on-entities-question)